# Hamilton-Jacobi equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Hamilton-Jacobi equation:

[image]

Using the method of Characteristics, one can define a curve $x(t)$ along which the PDE can be transformed into an ODE.
Let

[image]

so that

[image]

Differentiating the equation w.r.t. $x_i$, one can get

[image]

So let

[image]

then

[image]

Differentiating $z(t)$ w.r.t.  time results in the characteristic system of ODEs

[image]

Personally, I find $$\dot z(t)= D_pH \cdot p - H.$$

What am I missing?

PS: D denotes here the gradient

Comment: I would think that the author of the document I have made a typo mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, and the given formula for $\dot z$ is incorrect. Let's check on a simple example, inviscid Burgers: $u_t+uu_x=0$. Here $H=up$, hence $\dot x=D_pH=u$. Along the characteristic $u$ is constant, thus $\dot z\equiv 0$. This is in agreement with your formula: 
$$\dot z = (D_p H) p-H=up-up=0$$
but not with the formula for $\dot z$ in the quoted source.

You can also compare   with [lecture notes](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec06.pdf) by Xinwei Yu, where $H$ is not as general, but  the key points are the same.